# Use not exists instead of not in

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following query which gives correct result but I want to use not exist instead of not in.

```
 select cust_name from customer 
 where cust_id not in
    (select cust_id from ord where ord_id in
        (select ord_id from orderitem where prod_id in
            (select prod_id from product 
             WHERE PROD_DESCRIP = 'Guide to Tennis')))
```

Furthermore I have tried -

```
select cust_name from customer
where cust_id not exists
    (select cust_id from ord where ord_id in
        (select ord_id from orderitem where prod_id in
            (select prod_id from product
             WHERE PROD_DESCRIP = 'Guide to Tennis')))
```

I am not sure whether it is true or not

Comment: Learn the magic of inner joins and left joins.

Comment: I know but I am not getting proper answer from that. I am new in sql. So I think that's why facing issues

Comment: Can you add your create statement for the tables in the post--it's easier for folks to rewrite your query efficiently

Comment: You can use `show create table <your table>`

Comment: which table I should post here. I am confused. Is it okay to post- customer, ord and product table?

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the column name before `NOT EXISTS`, it's just `WHERE NOT EXISTS (subquery)`.

You then need to make it a correlated subquery, comparing the `cust_id` in the outer table with the `cust_id` in the inner table.

```
select cust_name
from customer AS c
where not exists
    (select 1 
     from ord AS o
     where ord_id in
        (select ord_id from orderitem where prod_id in
            (select prod_id from product WHERE PROD_DESCRIP = 'Guide to Tennis'))
        and o.cust_id = c.cust_id)
```

In general, it's better to use `JOIN` than `WHERE xxx IN` -- MySQL tends to optimize it better.

```
select cust_name
from customer AS c
where not exists
    (select 1 
     from ord AS o
     join orderitem AS oi ON o.ord_id = oi.ord_id
     join product AS p ON oi.prod_id = p.prod_id
     where p.prod_descrip = 'Guide to Tennis'
        and o.cust_id = c.cust_id)
```

And you can do the `NOT EXISTS` using a `LEFT JOIN` pattern.

```
select cust_name
from customer AS c
left join ord AS o ON o.cust_id = c.cust_id
left join orderitem AS oi ON o.ord_id = oi.ord_id
left join product AS p ON oi.prod_id = p.prod_id AND p.prod_descrip = 'Guide to Tennis'
where o.cust_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Give your question the correct tags, so that someone who knows Oracle will see it.